# c# foreach looping even number

Tags: c#

I have the following `foreach` loop in C#:

```
foreach(var item in mod)
{
    int i;

    i = i + 1;
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    { 
        string y = "even number"; 
    }
}
```

How come I get the message that local variable is unassigned. I am trying to find the even number here.

Comment: Are you sure this is where the error is? Did you omit any code?

Comment: Do you want i to increase each time the body of the loop is executed?

Comment: Because you tell the computer to calculate `i + 1` without defining `i`s initial value.

Comment: @NatePet did you have another question?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To resolve the message you are getting, you simply need to initialize it:

```
int i = 0;
```

If your intention is to count every item, then you will also need to change the scope of `i` to outside of the `foreach`.  Otherwise, as you originally posted, the variable `i` will have the same value for every iteration of the loop.

See this code snippet for both the initialization and scope change:

```
 int i = 0;
 foreach (var item in mod)
 {
     i = i + 1; // is the first item considered even or odd?  that answer changes where this should go

     if (i % 2 == 0) { 
         string y = "even number"; 
     }
 }
```

Comment: declaring outside the loop has nothing to do with it in this case.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Not for the actual error, but the code is logically wrong with the int inside the loop

Comment: Not necessarily. We don't know what he's using it for, and since the result is never used outside the loop, declaring it inside to reduce it's scope may very well be the proper thing.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I agree that it has nothing to do with this error.  I made the jump that the poster's intention was to do some type of counting with i.

Comment: It's possible, but given the even/odd check I see something more like printing out different styles for alternating rows as the loop runs.

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialise your `i` variable:

```
int i = 0;
```

You're currently trying + 1 to an unassigned variable.

Answer (score 4):

You get the warning because you are not assigning `i` before using it in `i = i + 1`. You want to declare `i` outside of your `foreach` loop, so you it isn't bound to the scope of the loop. Then initialize with `0` and use the increment feature. Something like:

```
int i = 0;
foreach (var item in mod)
{
    i++;

    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
        string y = "even number";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative to what others have suggested here (although correct) would be to use a for loop, this would take care of i for you, e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mod.length; i++)
{
    if (i % 2 == 0)
    {
      string y = "even number";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Change this: `int i;`

to this: `int i = 0;`

Values types in C# like int do have default values, but you're still not allowed to use an unassigned value-type variable.

Comment: The type is a red herring here. Both reference *and* value types have default values... but *local* variables need to be definitely assigned before use.

Comment: Good point about reference types - "null" is still a default value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign an initial value for `i` before you can do `i=i+1`

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize i. Right now the compiler is reading this as i = garbage in memory. So you have garbage in memory = garbage in memory + 1. That i could be equal to a string, a number, or anything.

```
 int i = 0;
```

In addition, you need to initialize that variable outside of the for...each loop, or it will keep resetting itself to 0.

```
 int i = 0;

 foreach(var item in mod){
     i = i + 1;

     if (i % 2 == 0) { 
         string y = "even number"; 
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   int i = 0;
   foreach(var item in mod)
   {
     if (i % 2 == 0) 
     { 
         string y = "even number"; 
     }
      i = i + 1;
    }
```

//what are you doing with y and how are you returning y if you need it.. 
are you expecting to break out at some point.. ? what if item has zero items..??